# Why isn't my clicklistener working?

Tags: java, libgdx

Here is my code

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;


public class MainMenuScreen extends SpaceInvaderScreen {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    TextureRegion background;
    Stage stage;
    TextButton playbutton;
    float time = 0;

    public MainMenuScreen(Game game){
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void show(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        background = new TextureRegion(new Texture("data/cool.jpg"), 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(1280, 1080));

        Skin uiskin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/skin/uiskin.json"));

        playbutton = new TextButton("Play", uiskin);
        playbutton.setWidth(200);
        playbutton.setHeight(100);
        playbutton.setPosition(980, 620);
        playbutton.setBounds(playbutton.getX(), playbutton.getY(),      playbutton.getWidth(), playbutton.getHeight());
        playbutton.addListener( new ClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                game.setScreen( new GameScreen(game));
                return true;
            };
        });
        stage.addActor(playbutton);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

        time += delta;

    }

    @Override
    public void hide(){
        batch.dispose();
        background.getTexture().dispose();
    }
}
```

i'm not sure whats going on with the clicklistener as to why it doesn't work. I also tried using the touchDown method but it doesn't work either. Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, im fairly new to the library

Comment: Can you also post the Game, GameScreen and SpaceInvaderScreen code?

Answer (score 0):

Just two things to try: I can see that you're building the button in the show method. Why? It makes much more sense to have a setup method and build the whole layout of the application / game / whatever in that setup method *before* showing anything. But this is just a shot in the dark, I don't know this framework you are using and I might be very well wrong.

Also another thing that might cause problems when you keep multiple instances of the same game! Watch out to build the game once and only once, and pass that single instance around. Why is that important? Because there might be a case that you are calling `game.setScreen( new GameScreen(game));` but on the wrong instance!

Please post your `SpaceInvaderScreen` as well so it might be easier to debug it.

And anyway, have you tried debugging the `touchDown` method? Is it called at all?

Also two more things: `ClickListener` is a class. Not an interface. So when you are overriding the `touchDown` method, then you are basically bypassing the parent code in the superclass.

Try calling as the first line in the touchdown method:

```
super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
```

Also the [ClickListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html) documentation says:

> when true is returned, the event is handled (...) This does not affect
>   event propagation inside scene2d, but causes the Stage event methods
>   to return true, which will eat the event so it is not passed on to the
>   application under the stage.

So you should try returning false;

Comment: The framework is libgdx, and the show method is called when you call the screen instance, so in a sense it is a setup method. The render method is the one that is called and updates.

Comment: Can you also post the Game, GameScreen and SpaceInvaderScreen code?

Comment: `
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;  

public class GameScreen extends SpaceInvaderScreen {
 
 Game game;  
 public GameScreen(Game game) {  
  super(game);  
 }  
 
 @Override  
 public void show(){
  
 }
 
 @Override  
 public void render(float delta) {  
  
 }  
 
 @Override  
 public void hide(){
  
 }

}
`

Comment: `
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public abstract class SpaceInvaderScreen implements Screen {
 Game game;
 
 public SpaceInvaderScreen(Game game){
  this.game = game;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void resize(int width, int height){
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void show(){
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void hide(){
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void pause(){
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void resume(){
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void dispose(){
  
 }
}`

Comment: That's cool but you can edit your original question and paste the code there. :)

Comment: `

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.jfeng.spaceinvaders.screens.MainMenuScreen;

public class SpaceInvaders extends Game {
 @Override
 public void create () {
  setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
 }
}
`
this is the original game which starts the game; my GameScreen is empty as of now, as I am trying to fix my button first. SpaceInvaderScreen is just an extension of the Screen class from the library with a constructor

Comment: oh lol, i think it wouldn't fit in the character limit though right?

Comment: @maziodyne Can you try calling super.touchdown() in your click listener? Because what you are actually doing now is that you are bypassing the original touchdown code. I am not sure that this helps, but makes sense calling it.

Comment: @maziodyne Also I checked the Clicklistener documentations and it says when you return true from touchdown it "Marks this event as handled. This does not affect event propagation inside scene2d, but causes the Stage event methods to return true, which will eat the event so it is not passed on to the application under the stage."                  Did you try returning false?

Comment: Somehow I fixed the problem, not sure how. But heres what i changed

`playbutton.addListener( new ClickListener() {  
      public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){  
       game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game);         return true;  
      }  `

Comment: Great. But this code that you posted doesn't compile. Anyway. I am glad that you solved it.